# How can you determine whether a surgical mask is real or fake?

Tags: covid-19, ppe

There are lots of surgical masks being sold online rather than traditional outlets such as home improvement shops and chemists.  How do you ascertain it is likely to be a real mask that provides protection versus a fake?

Answer (score 3):

3 of the tests are based on the fact that the surgical mask is

- 3 ply
- The outer layer is water proof
- the middle layer is a plastic filter that doesn't burn like paper

There are also electrostatic and breath tests.

See

- [image: three ply]
- [Water test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiaa_eB98A0&feature=emb_logo)
- [Flameability test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=8&v=azinyNrCW1s&feature=emb_logo)
- [Electrostatic and breath test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC0Hga10nbk)

https://medium.com/@ximplifyit/genuine-or-fake-surgical-masks-3-quick-tests-to-find-out-df8c27c27a42